# Не срабатывает добавление в корзину

Tags: php

Когда я пытаюсь дбавить в корзину, меня перекидывает на `/add2basket.php?id=1` и ничего не приходит, а, по идее, должна брать id, т.е. 1, и добавлять в массив.

- Куки записываються нормально.
- [Код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75d399c9ec677f585a7c3cf9cbc42cfa3961e8dc).
- [Полностью папка (zip)](https://mega.co.nz/#!UM42CDib!-TS9YyPwAhLCPPYlAEs3FTTK2Z2dM8Awp_r2YRhec9E).

**Обновление**

```
function clearInt($data){
    return abs((int)$data);
}

function clearStr($data){
    global $link;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim(strip_tags($data)));
}
```

Comment: Что делает функция clearInt?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.